# JSONParser error - System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('r' (code 114))

Tags: apex, webservices, json

Im trying to parse the following JSON from a web service callout, however im getting the above error on this line:

```
while(parser.nextToken() != null)
```

Is it to do with the '\' in the json?? if so how do i deal with it? Appreciate any suggestions?

```
{   "place_id":"12037085",
"licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright",
"osm_type":"node",
"osm_id":"1112205402",
"boundingbox":[51.4660524,51.4661524,-0.1537554,-0.1536554],
"lat":"51.4661024",
"lon":"-0.1537054",
"display_name":"Nany Lamb Indonesian, Woodmere Close, Clapham Junction, London Borough of Wandsworth, London, Greater London, England, SW11, United Kingdom, European Union",
"class":"amenity",
"type":"restaurant",
"importance":0.401,
"icon":"http:\/\/open.mapquestapi.com\/nominatim\/v1\/images\/mapicons\/food_restaurant.p.20.png",
"address":
    {
    "restaurant":"Nany Lamb Indonesian",
    "road":"Woodmere Close",
    "suburb":"Clapham Junction",
    "city":"London Borough of Wandsworth",
    "county":"London",
    "state_district":"Greater London",
    "state":"England","postcode":"SW11",
    "country":"United Kingdom",
    "country_code":"gb",
    "continent":"European Union"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parsing this in Apex, correct?

I was able to feed your sample JSON into [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) and generate strongly typed Apex classes to parse it. The one issue here was the `class` member as it conflicted with a reserved Apex keyword. See [How do you deserialize json properties that are reserved words in apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-deserialize-json-properties-that-are-reserved-words-in-apex)

Debugging the license member gave:

> Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

And icon:

> http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/food_restaurant.p.20.png

So it seemed to parse fine with the exception of the reserved keyword.