# Serialize JSON attribute that is a reserved keyword in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, regular-expressions, serialization

To use [the Javascript tree library DynaTree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h4.1) on my Visualforce page I create JSON data in its controller

```
List<DynaTreeNode> rootNodes = nodesByParentId.get(null).values();   
dynaTreeJson = JSON.serialize(rootNodes);
dynaTreeJson = dynaTreeJson.replaceAll('select_X', 'select');
```

To construct the nodes I use this Apex class

```
public virtual class DynaTreeNode {
    //...
    public Boolean select_X = false;
    public Boolean hideCheckbox = false;
}
```

The problem is that the Javascript expect a property called `select` which I cannot use as a name in Apex as it is a **reserved (SOQL) keyword**. [According to this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-deserialize-json-properties-that-are-reserved-words-in-apex) I prefixed it with `_X` and do a `replaceAll()` on the output.

The problem is that I now run into expeception when used on large JSON strings.

> System.LimitException: Regex too complicated Error is in expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where instead of an Apex class with fields a `Map<String, Object>` can be used instead because the map keys can be any valid string. Convert the `DynaTreeNode` objects to `Map<String, Object>` objects before you serialize:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> toSerializableForm(List<DynaTreeNode> rootNodes) {
    ...
}
```

Tedious I know.

(Or use `Map<String, Object>` everywhere instead of `DynaTreeNode`.)