# Better way to do the JSON.deserializeUntyped to avoid cognitive complexity

Tags: apex, webservices, deserialize

I have use-case to call an external web service response in a Batch class. I have desterilized and build the Wrapper from the response like below,

Sample Response

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "description": "Match 2 Type",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "dsda",
            "typess": "sad",
            "numberss": "sdada",
            "brand": "fdasd",
            "model": "",
            "year": "",
            "plate_no": "dasad",
            "vin_no": "",
            "timezone": "Something"
         },
         {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "fafa",
            "typess": "afafsa",
            "numberss": "asd",
            "brand": "adasd",
            "model": "",
            "year": "",
            "plate_no": "adsada",
            "vin_no": "",
            "timezone": "Something"
        }
    ]
}

public with sharing class RetrieveInfoService {

public List<WrapperInfo> buildWrapper() {
// Instantiate a new http object
Http http = new Http();
// Instantiate a new HTTP request.
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(InfoEndPoint);
req.setMethod('GET');

System.debug('Response' + http.send(req).getBody());
    
HttpResponse infoResponse = http.send(req);

List<WrapperInfo> lstInfo = new List<WrapperInfo>();

Map<String, Object> mapInfo;
List<Object> lstInfoObject;
if (infoResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    mapInfo = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(infoResponse.getBody());
    lstInfoObject = (List<Object>) mapInfo.get('data');

    WrapperInfo info;
    for(Object obj : lstInfoObject) {
      Map<String, Object> p = (Map<String, Object>) obj;

      info = new WrapperInfo();
         for(String s : p.keySet()) {
             if(s.equals('id')) {
                info.Id = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('name')) {
                info.Name = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('typess')) {
                 info.Typess = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('numberss')) {
                 info.simNumber = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('brand')) {
                 info.Brand = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('model')) {
                 info.Model = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('year')) {
                 info.Year = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('plate_no')) {
                 info.PlateNumber = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('vin_no')) {
                 info.VinNumber = (String) p.get(s);
             } else if (s.equals('timezone')) {
                 info.timeZone = (String) p.get(s);
             } 
          }

          lstInfo.add(deviceInfo);
          }
    }

    return  lstInfo; 
}

public class WrapperInfo {

    public String Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public String Typess {get;set;}
    public String simNumber {get;set;}
    public String Brand {get;set;}
    public String Model {get;set;}
    public String Year {get;set;}
    public String PlateNumber {get;set;}
    public String VinNumber {get;set;}
    public String timeZone {get;set;}
    }

}
```

But when I ran the PMD tool against the above implementation I am getting cognitive complexity issue, Is there any better way that I can use to build the wrapper class?

Comment: Convert json to a wrapper using Json2Apex heroku app, and then deserialize `deserialize(jsonString, apexType)` it to that wrapper class instead of using deserializeUntyped.

Comment: Is there any benefits compare to desterilize method?

Comment: Or write your own classes (like your "wrapper") and deserialize directly with that (you don't have to generate code in order to do this; we don't use Json2Apex but have plenty of cases where we parse JSON into complex Apex "[POTATO](https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1100481781537468417?s=20)" object trees. We take this approach because we have fine control over how the objects are organized and can apply patterns we commonly use).

Comment: The massive benefits of directly using `deserialize` is that you don't have to write all that code, it is faster to parse the data and it is generic (it works with any POTATOs you create).

Comment: I see your response has a reserved character and I think this answer your question? [How do you deserialize json properties that are reserved words in apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-deserialize-json-properties-that-are-reserved-words-in-apex)

Comment: Hi Raul, No I have just modified the response to put to the question. There is no reserved character in the Response. Thanks.

Comment: `number` is a reserved character when you try to declare the variable in wrapper for deserializing.

Comment: sorry, again the same, I can't put the real response here, so modified and mistakenly put the reserved characters. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. But I am getting the cognitive complexity warning while running pmd against the above implementation. Is there any better way we can avoid it in the above implemetation.

Comment: +1 Phil, POTATO: that gave me a good laugh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the hand-crafted deserialization code and do something like:

```
public with sharing class RetrieveInfoService {
    public List<WrapperInfo> buildWrapper() {
        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http http = new Http();

        // Instantiate a new HTTP request.
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setEndpoint(InfoEndPoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');
    
        HttpResponse infoResponse = http.send(req);

        System.debug('Response' + infoResponse.getBody());

        if (infoResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
            Response response = JSON.deserialize(infoResponse.getBody(), Response.class);

            // This could be null or empty, so you might want to do a bit more
            // here before returning the data from the response
            return response.data; 
        }

        return new List<WrapperInfo>();
    }

    public class Response {
        public String status {get; set;}
        public String description {get; set;}
        public List<WrapperInfo> data {get; set;}
    }

    public class WrapperInfo {
        public String id {get;set;}
        public String name {get;set;}
        public String typess {get;set;}
        public String numbers {get;set;}
        public String brand {get;set;}
        public String model {get;set;}
        public String year {get;set;}
        public String plate_no {get;set;}
        public String vin_no {get;set;}
        public String timezone {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Note that I have made sure there is an object to contain the top-level details, and I have made sure that all the properties for the "wrapper" match the naming in the JSON.